# Reproducible pixel perfect JPEG decoding

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to convert JPEG files to PPM files in a reproducible way so that a certain JPEG file will always convert to the same PPM file, regardless of the computer where the conversion is run.

Doing a simple

```
convert -compress none src.jpeg dest.ppm
```

will result in slightly different PPM files depending on which version of imagemagick in installed. I suppose different defaults are used in different versions.

This problem can be reproduced converting an image on a Ubuntu 12.04 box and on a Ubuntu 14.04 box and then comparing the two PPMs with `compare -compose src img1.ppm img2.ppm`.

Is there a way to specify all the parameters that influence the JPEG decoding? Or is there an alternative decoder that is guaranteed to always produce the same pixel values?

Comment: Mmmm, no too sure about this one, but try `convert -compress none src.jpeg -colorspace RGB dest.ppm` as the default colourspace changed a while back. Another problem is that one IM may have 8-bit while another has 16-bit quantisation. Check your Q setting with `convert xc: -format "%q" info:`

Comment: Some slight variations would be expected as JPEG is a lossy format, and the systems architecture (quntum range & HDRI) will influence decoding coefficient values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by the comments, there are two issues to be solved here. DCT quantization and colorspaces.

The default choice of DCT uses the machine-dependent floating point code and this may lead to small variations. This can be fixed using the option `-define jpeg:dct-method=islow` that selects a precise integer-based DCT.

The support for colorspaces has changed a lot in the past releases and so it is hard to get reproducible results out of the box. Getting this right in general is a problem, but in my case I can get away with producing unfaithful colors, as long as they are the same everywhere. This can be achieved by forcing imagemagick to interpret the source data as linear RGB and to always produce linear RGB using the commands `-set colorspace RGB -colorspace RGB`.

The final command is then

```
convert src.jpeg \
    -define jpeg:dct-method=islow
    -set colorspace RGB -colorspace RGB \
    -compress none dest.ppm
```